# How to export application oracle apex with all data in all tables using supporting objects?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to export/import an oracle apex application between two different workspaces.
i have already tried to create supporting objects then export the application and import it to the other workspace but i found all tables were empty.
how can i export the application with all data in tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting oracle APEX 21.2 there is a feature called "data packager" that allows you to export tables with their data. Google this for some examples it probably meets your needs.

Comment: first of all thank you so match,i did like you said but i got an error  no file generated

Comment: Happy to look into it if you create a workspace on apex.oracle.com where you reproduce this and give me credentials.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you would need liquibase and sqlcl installed.

With this, you can run liquibase command :

- lb genobject -type apex -applicationid
- lb genobject -type schema -name